# Hash functions to the power of two and three notation

Tags: hash, universal-hash

I have found in a Wireless Sensor Networks security paper, operations where cryptographic hash functions are elevated to the power of 2 and to the power of 3 (i.e. $h^2(x)$ and $h^3(x)$).

This might be a very simple question but I haven't found this notation in other literature. I wonder: does this notation mean that you need to compute the hash twice or thrice (i.e. $h(h(x))$ and $h(h(h(x)))$?

In the paper, $h$ is defined as a collision free one-way hash function.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these notations always seem to mean that `H^n(x)` (or $H^n(x)$ in mathematical notation) means that $x$ is the first input, and that the next outputs are a hash of the previous output:

```
H^0(x) = x           // just defined as x below
H^1(x) = H(x)
H^2(x) = H(H^1(x)) = H(H(x))
H^3(x) = H(H^2(x)) = ... = H(H(H(x)))
H^4(x) = ............... = H(H(H(H(x))))
...
```

so another way to define it is $H^n(x)=H(H^{n-1}(x))$ where $H^0(x)=x$. I've used uppercase `H` as that seems to be more common.

The construct seems to comply with [the exponentiation property within abstract algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#In_abstract_algebra) as [only the less strong power associativity is required for the *function composition* of the (hash) functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222546/229184) (beware - the answer on the math site requires some mathematical background).

---

Usually this kind of construction is used for key stretching; a method of calculating a key from a password (or other low entropy secret) that includes a work factor. In other words, both the user and an attacker are required to perform a number of operations, which makes attacking the password harder.

Comment: This is common notation in mathematics in general, not just crypto.

Comment: I've asked if this notation is mathematically correct [here (on the math site)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222546/229184)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about with associativity. Associativity is a property of *binary* operations; a hash is not a binary function. Associativity isn't a thing with unary functions. *Composing* iterated hash functions is a binary operation, but that's associative in every sense.

Comment: @cpast Paŭlo explainted this nicely on the math site, seems you are right about the above comment. I won't copy Paŭlo's answer in though, I guess that's a bit too much for the less mathematically inclined.